# index match vba loop

Tags: excel, vba, indexing, match

I am attempting to write a macro that generates e-mail addresses automatically based on first names, last names, and company. I have a worksheet where I have collected my raw data (first, last, firm) and a final column for the e-mail address I am trying to generate using the macro.

On a second sheet, the first row pulls the first name , last name, and firm from the previously mentioned sheet. Below, I have a table that generates the e-mail address based on the format I have assigned for each company.(i.e First.Last@abc.com,FLast@abc.com) using the name on the top row.

I will then use index match to match that pulls the generated e-mail by matching the firm: Index(email list,Match(firm,firm list,0).

How can I use VBA to loop through this for my list?

All help is appreciated!

Comment: I can't be certain, but from your description it doesn't sound like you need VBA for this. Some lookup formulas should do it.

Comment: There are 3 formats: First.Last@company.com, FLast@company.com, First@company.com but there are 55 companies

Comment: Basically, I am trying to write a code that will say: Sheet2 A1=Sheet1A1(Firm Name) then Sheet2 B1 = Sheet1 B1(First Name) then Sheet2 C1 = Sheet1 C1(Last Name). Sheet1D1 = Index(Sheet2 D3:D57(possible e-mails)MATCH(Sheet1A1(Firm Name), Sheet2 A3:A57,0)).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this will work:

[image]